# Visual Studio on 4k monitor (dialog boxes not scaling)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

So we've recently had our dev machines replaced with 4k laptops and windows 10.  I've got visual studio set up, the DPI scaling has worked for the most part to make things usable.  The only problem is errors / dialog boxes.

I can't find a way to make them scale up to something readable. Instead I'm getting unintelligable errors written for ants.

Has anyone had any experience of this issue on high DPI screens?  And if so did you find a way to fix the problem?

As an example of what I'm talking about, content is scaled, but the options to the left are not.  If I get an error popup (exceptions, build failed etc) then everything is in that tiny text, making it unreadable.

[image]

Comment: Lower the resolution?

Comment: That's my fallback plan.

Comment: ROFL. This shows how far we are in high DPI awareness. Even MS can't do it right.

Comment: the sad part is, I could understand if it were some third party legacy app.  But it's Visual Studio.  This is the application people are going to be using to make applications for these 4k devices.